# Add mouse event listener to OBJMTL object - three.js

Tags: json, three.js, mouseevent, listener

I have created a OBJMTL 3D object with:

```
                    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                    loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                        Barrel = event.content;

                        side: THREE.DoubleSide;

                        scene.add(Barrel);
                    });


                    loader.load( '3D/Barrel/barrel.obj', '3D/Barrel/barrel.mtl');
```

I want to add an mouse event listener like in this : 
[link](http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/)

Any other example of creating mouse listeners i found around the web does not work with OBJMTL loaded objects.

Any idea?